# How to not display an image if outside of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple images within a div, I change thier positions using JQuery

```
$("#"+carElem).css({"left": pos.left+50 +"px"});
```

Im using absolute positioning (relative positioning gives the same result), is it possible to cut off anything that is displayed outside of the parent div .i.e make sure its not shown?

Comment: Do you mean [`overflow: hidden`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html)?

Comment: Or you mean hide the whole image that goes outside the boundaries?

Comment: Just the part that goes off the boundaries.
Sorry for the bad description, i'm trying few approaches at the same time and the code looks confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give the parent div the style `overflow: hidden` and go back to relative positioning (it won't work with absolute positioning).

There's probably a better way to solve the actual underlying issue, though, if we had a bit more context. But `overflow: hidden` will probably be part of it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do that

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    // place images here...
</div>
```